# Broke my website with .htaccess! How to reset?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I was trying to remove ".php" from the URL with [this](http://www.chrishjorth.com/blog/one-com-codeigniter-htaccess-rewrite-rules/), but now my website is completely broken. The index page works, but everything else prints out

> *mysite.com/subfolder/subfolder?about.php*

when it should be

> *mysite.com/about.php*

I've tried modifying the file, but can't get it back to the way it was...

Is there any way I can reset everything? I've tried searching for a solution and turning the RewriteEngine Off/On, but no luck there...

I'm using [One.com](http://one.com) for hosting if that matters.

```
# @author: Chris Hjorth, www.chrishjorth.com
# Make index.php the directory index page
DirectoryIndex index.php
#Protect the .htaccess files
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subfolder/
# START CodeIgniter ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# based on http://www.danielwmoore.com/extras/index.php?topic=7691.0 and http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/132758/
# Redirect default controller to "/".
# This is to prevent duplicated content. (/welcome/index =&gt; /)
RewriteRule ^(welcome(/index)?)/?$ /subfolder/ [L,R=301]
# Remove /index/ segment on the URL, again to prevent duplicate content.
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index/? $1 [L,R=301]
# Remove trailing slashes, also to remove duplicate content
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Remove multiple slashes in between, just to remove the possibility of fabricating crazy links.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
# Ignore certain files and folders in this rewrite
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|frameworks|uploads|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
# [NC] = no case - case insensitive
# [L] = Last rule, last rewrite for this set of conditions
# [QSA] = Query String Append, should be used to prevent all redirects from going to your default controller, which happens on
# some server configurations.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/index.php?$1 [NC,L,QSA]
# END CodeIgniter --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
</IfModule>
# If Mod_ewrite is NOT installed go to index.php
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

[SOLVED]:

The problem was cache. Firefox had saved the htaccess config, so no matter what I changed it wouldn't remove the broken rewriting. So thanks for the input, people!

Comment: post your .htaccess here. So only we know what is the mistake.

Comment: I've linked to it in the text, but I can post it here as well if you want.

Comment: Why dont you just remove everything, save the file, reload your website and then edit it again? Worked for me every time. Don't forget to refresh the website using F5 or browser button. Some browsers tend to cache .htaccess and this prevents them from using the cached version.

Comment: Holy smokes, you were right. I'd tried a hard refresh and all, but it was somehow cached. I've nearly been ripping my hair out the last hour because of this broken .htaccess stuff. So thank you! Funny how it's always something blatantly obvious...

Comment: If a change you made to your `.htaccess` file breaks yor site, then just remove that last change and it should be back to how it was before. Apache reads the `.htaccess` file for each page/resource access so only effects Apache's activity if it exists. Undo your last change and you are back to where you were.

Comment: To add to what @Riggs has said - always take a backup before tinkering with htaccess files, so you can reset to a working condition if you break it.

Comment: Very good point @halfer! And I did reset everything, @RiggsFolly, but Firefox had cached the broken version somehow and wouldn't let go until I manually cleared the cache... Strange, but all good now!

Comment: I've sometimes found fixing an htaccess file doesn't immediately clear a problem - they can sometimes be voodoo! However Firefox does not cache this file - it doesn't even read it. Could have been a cookies problem though.

Answer (score 0):

A search on CodeIgniter +htaccess gave met the below htaccess.

https://gist.github.com/philipptempel/4226750

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  # !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and leading
  #  slashes.
  # If your page resides at
  #  http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
  # then use
  # RewriteBase /mypage/test1/
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
  # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
  # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Though this is not realy CodeIgniter special, it should get you back on track again. From there on please look carefully in the documentation to understand what you are changing

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 0):

Open config.php and do following replaces

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php"
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = ""
```

Just replace

```
$config['uri_protocol'] ="AUTO"
```

to

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI"
```

AND IN HTACCESS FILE put following code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```